# jQuery Tooltips only in HTML Code but not visible

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I am trying to get some good looking help buttons on my website with jQuery and tooltips.

However they appear when you search the Element but they don't show.

Here's some code:

```
<div class="card-header">
    <h5 style="float: left">Eckdaten</h5>
    <button id="help" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" 
            title="TestTest" style="float: right; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px">
        <i class="fas fa-life-ring"> <Hilfe
    </button>
</div>
```

in script section:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

src files:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.js"> 
</script>
```

Whenever hovered, a tooltip appears in the html code but the actual box isn't showing.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid HTML structure there. Your *font awesome* icon needs to be closed.

Replace `<Hilfe` with closed `</i>` will fix the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/2dqa1fvu/4/

[image]

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your hint and especially the fiddle. The Problem was actually not the <i> tag but that i used bootstrap and Jquery as a source, when i deleted them everything worked fine. So thank you for the fiddle because it showed me that i dont need to import them :)

Comment: @KLanger: hmmmm? Now I am confused. Do you want to use jQuery tooltip or bootstrap tooltip? To use jQuery tooltip, you need to reference jqueryui package. To use bootstrap tooltip, you need to reference bootstrap and popperjs. You need jQuery in both cases. My fiddle did reference bootstrap and its dependent resources. Click "Resources" on the left menu bar.